# creating a function that returns a table in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my function

```
create or replace FUNCTION split(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ':'
) RETURN TABLE  
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT trim(regexp_substr(i_str, '[^'||i_delim||']+', 1, LEVEL)) str 
    FROM projet
    CONNECT BY instr(i_str, i_delim, 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0;
END;
```

this is the error code

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + ; case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an altern
Errors: check compiler log
```

if someone can help me correct this code so it can function correctly

Comment: Can a function return a `TABLE`? I don't know. You would typically return a `SYS_REFCURSOR`, if you want to return a selected dataset.

Comment: yes it can i have seen that in many documents but the problem is the syntax somehow is not correct for reasons unknown to me

Comment: `return table` is a T-SQL construct, not something that you can do in PL/SQL.  PL/SQL does have pipelined table functions https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-FUNCTION-statement.html, the ```RETURN``` clause needs to reference a datatype. That can be an oracle defined datatype or a user defined datatype. "TABLE" is not a datatype. Maybe you could explain what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `RETURN SELECT` is also not the way Oracle do this. You should check very detailed [description in docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm) to correct your syntax

Comment: Also you may not need to reinvent the wheel, because Oracle already have done this task with [APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/STRING_TO_TABLE-Function.htm#AEAPI185). Ask your DBA if this is available to be used by you (I do not know licensing policy on this package)

Comment: is there a way to return multiple records without making the return value a table type?

Comment: @imstuckaf so what type do you want it to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to return a data set is using a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. Such a function cannot be called from SQL, but from programming languages including PL/SQL und C# for instance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split
(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ':'
) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(i_str, '[^'||i_delim||']+', 1, LEVEL)) str 
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY instr(i_str, i_delim, 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0;
  RETURN v_cursor;
END split;
```

Another way to return a data set is a pipelined function. For this you need to create a matching collection type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_table_of_varchar2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split
(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ':'
) RETURN type_table_of_varchar2 PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(i_str, '[^'||i_delim||']+', 1, LEVEL)) AS str 
    FROM projet
    CONNECT BY instr(i_str, i_delim, 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  ) LOOP
    PIPE ROW (rec.str);
  END LOOP;
END split;
```

The pipelined function can be called from SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE( split('ABC:DEF:GHI') );
```

I've replaced `FROM projet` by `FROM DUAL` by the way, because your query does nothing related to `projet` table data.

Comment: thanks, the pipeline way kinda worked but it generates around 150 records after processing ```('ABC:DEF:GHI')``` , when use it with my database ``` select split(id_objectifs) from projet``` the processing takes forever: somehow it keeps iterating with no end

Comment: the cursor solution compiles normally but when executed it generates this error:
```ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item```

Comment: It should work. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79c7a5b50e05c4ff3f16dac8df68b6d1. Are you trying to call this function from SQL? As mentioned in the first paragraph of my answer, this is not possible.

Comment: yes that is what i'm trying to do, i want to create the function split() so i can use it in an SQL query :
```
select split(projects_ids) from project where project.id=X
```
i dont know if that's possible but i'm just trying to find a solution

Comment: This can't work, because your split query splits a string into multiple rows. The string 'ABC:DEF' gets split into two rows, one with the string 'ABC', the other with the string 'DEF'. In the select clause of a query however, you work on a single row. You cannot `select split(projects_ids)`. You can only select *from* rows. And my first query is not allowed to be called from SQL anyway. You'd have to use the second one. And then use `CROSS APPLY` probably.

Comment: Your problem, however, is really your inappropriate data model. Why do you store multiple IDs in one string? This is not how a relational database is supposed to be designed. Fix this and you don't need the function at all.

Comment: i know this is not the best way to work with databases but the problem is that i am working with APEX which stores the selected IDs of a checkbox that way, i tried to work with appropriate method but i would have to make so much customized code, and thanks a lot mate you were the most helpful